# Have a dual-monitor setup with a docking station. I want to duplicate the main monitor to a wall-mounted display

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

My Work setup includes a dell laptop attached to a docking station that then splits the video signal to two monitors using Display Port. My office has a small meeting area and I have a 55" tv mounted on the wall. I need to duplicate the main monitor (of the dual monitor setup) on the 55" TV and still continue to see the screen on the dual monitor setup. Essentially I want to be able to display my main monitor on the wall TV when I turn the TV on. It is OK if it is always sending the signal. I CAN hardwire the setup if needed, but I didn't know if there were wireless options - wireless would be much easier to setup. What I thought would work is a display port splitter that would split the signal coming out of the docking station to my main monitor of the dual monitor setup and a display port to HDMI adapter on the splitter port that is going to the wall monitor. I could then use wireless HDMI to go from there to the 55" (but it could not be over WiFi (I don't have access to the office wifi).

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: If the network adapter on your dell laptop supports it, you could share the wireless connection of your laptop with the TV. Connect the TV Wifi to your laptop mobile hotspot, and then if it's a smart TV, with any luck you can test screen casting your laptop to the TV if there is an app available to install on the TV to support that. What is the model number and brand of the TV?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPwNt9VgcFo

Comment: @Mastaxx - that worked beautifully! I forget that smart TVs can be the target to push out wireless display. One last question - the "connect to wireless display" feature is buried in the settings. Is there a way to create a one click desktop button to enable it with the same settings every time?  (duplicate Monitor to wall, extend to the monitor on desk)? Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that worked! I've posted an answer below for you with the best workflow i can think of for you (without diving into elaborate scripting ideas).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to auto connect to a specific wireless display and cast a specific screen in one click, at least not without getting very scripty about it (AutoHotKey etc..).

However, the following main and additional instructions should allow you to simplify the process as much as possible and still achieve the desired workflow.

**1. Go to Mobile Hotspot within Network and Internet Options**

[image]

**2. Choose "WiFi". Edit the hotspot to custom name/password and switch it on**

[image]

**3. On the TV > Connect to the WiFi hotspot now being broadcasted from the laptop**

**4. On the laptop, search the start menu for "Connect to a wireless display"**

[image]

**5. Select your TV from the list of available devices and choose which screen you want to cast.**

**Tips:**

There doesn't appear to be direct way to launch the casting direct to a specific device in one click. However, you can simplify the process by calling upon displayswitch.exe through the use of a .bat file:

**1. Create a new text document on the desktop and name it.**

**2. Paste `%windir%\system32\displayswitch.exe` into the document and save it.**

[image]

**3. Open a new explorer window and make sure in the "View" options at the top you have "File Name Extensions" ticked.**

[image]

**4. Navigate to the .txt file on the desktop and rename it to say .bat instead.**

[image]

**5. Double click the .bat file and you should find this immediately brings up the display switch side bar to select your desired casting screen + connect to your wireless display.**

[image]